# Find and replace text into txt with batch language

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a problem with the code ...
I have the files t1.txt and t2.txt. The goal is to move from file 1 to file 2 with the same content unless it contains a specific word, in which case, the entire line must be replaced by a predefined one.

specifically I have problems with the 'if' and with the reassignment of the variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set p1=t1.txt
set p2=t2.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%p1%) do (
    set nl=%%a
    if not "%n1%"=="%n1:texto=%" (
        set n1=replace with this text
    )
    echo !n1! >> %p2%
)
pause>nul
exit
```

Comment: This is easy in C#. Don't use this batch language, it's like nearly 40 years old. Use something more modern. Powershell could do it.

Comment: This is the most asked reason for failing batches. If setting and using a variable in a (code block) enable delayed expansion **AND** replace the `%` enclosing a variable with an `!` (not the for meta variables) you do this once correctly in the echo, but miss it in the if command. `if not "!n1!"=="!n1:texto=!"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variables in batch not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: Why are you using delayed expansion for echoing but not for comparing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is possible with pure batch scripting, but it is not that trivial when you want it in a safe manner, with respect to certain special characters and to not lose empty lines of the original file. So here is a way:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_IFILE=t1.txt"   & rem // (input file to be processed)
set "_OFILE=t2.txt"   & rem // (output file to be returned)
set "_WORD=\<texto\>" & rem // (string to search in lines, `findstr` regular expression)
set "_REPL=replace with this text" & rem // (text to replace lines containing the word)

rem // Output to console if no output file is provided:
if not defined _OFILE set "_OFILE=con"
rem /* Initialise a loop counter which should be synchronous to the line number, unless
rem    a line matches the search string, so it becomes skipped and the numbers differ: */
set /A "LCNT=0"
rem // Write to output file:
> "%_OFILE%" (
    rem /* Read from input file, prefix every line by a line number + `:`, skip lines
    rem    matching the search string: */
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('cmd /V /C findstr /V /N /R /C:"!_WORD!" "!_IFILE!"') do (
        rem // Split off the line number from the line string:
        for /F "delims=:" %%K in ("%%L") do (
            rem // Increment loop counter:
            set /A "LCNT+=1"
            rem // Store current line (including line number prefix):
            set "LINE=%%L"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion in order to avoid trouble with `!`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Check whether loop counter and line number differ:
            if !LCNT! lss %%K (
                rem /* Numbers differ, hence return the replace line as many times
                rem    as the difference is: */
                set /A "DIFF=%%K-LCNT"
                for /L %%D in (1,1,!DIFF!) do echo(!_REPL!
            )
            rem // Return line with line number prefix removed:
            echo(!LINE:*:=!
            endlocal
            rem // Synchronise loop counter with line number:
            set "LCNT=%%K"
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Restrictions:

- lines must not exceed a length of about 8190 characters (limited by [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and [variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) lengths);
- the search expression must not be longer than 254 characters (limited by [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html));
- the input text file must be ASCII/ANSI-encoded ([`cmd`](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) might handle other files wrongly, depending on the current [code page](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html));
- the input text file should not contain characters with a code above `0x7F` (`cmd` might change such characters to others, depending on the current code page);
- the input text file must have DOS/Windows-style line endings (Unix-style line endings are understood, but the output text file is going to have DOS/Windows-style line endings then; MAC-style line endings are not supported at all);

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it is what I was looking for. I am starting in this language and it is difficult to find reliable sources, do you have documentation to share?

Comment: You're welcome! I usually refer to http://ss64.com/nt/, which provides way more information than the help pages (`/?`)...

Answer (score 0):

The command **FOR** always ignores empty lines and by default it ignores also lines starting with a semicolon. On usage of delayed expansion also lines containing an exclamation mark are modified on execution of command line `set nl=%%a` in the loop. So a solution using **FOR** could be the completely wrong attempt depending on content of file `t1.txt`.

Download [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript and store it in same directory as the batch file below.

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto :EOF
if not exist "t1.txt" goto :EOF

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^.*textto.*$" "replace with this text" /F "t1.txt" /O "t2.txt"

rem Compare the two files binary with ignoring the differences. Delete file
rem t1.txt if a line was modified by JREPL.BAT. Otherwise move file t1.txt
rem over t2.txt to keep the last modification date of file t1.txt for t2.txt.
%SystemRoot%\System32\fc.exe /B "t1.txt" "t2.txt" >nul
if errorlevel 1 ( del "t1.txt" ) else move /Y "t1.txt" "t2.txt"
```

`jrepl.bat` searches with a regular expression for lines containing `textto` and replaces all such lines by `replace with this text`. All other lines are copied unmodified from input file `t1.txt` to output file `t2.txt`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `fc /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `rem /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`

Comment: Thanks, but it is a script that I need for many computers with different versions of windows and, in general, with low resources, so I prefer to do it entirely in batch.

Comment: @JuanComande No problem. `jrepl.bat` works also on every Windows machine including Windows XP because of using Windows scripting host which is a native installed component of Windows. However, if the solution posted by [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) is better for you, it's okay. I posted this solution because of nothing was posted by you about the character encoding of text file `t1.txt` and its content. There is perhaps a much easier __FOR__ loop possible, but we can't suggest one without knowing file content.